# Reference request: Axiomatic treatment of multiplicative functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

I'm currently reading Apostol's analytic number theory, Chapter 2 on multiplicative functions. While the current exposition is nice, I can't help but feel that there has to been some algebraic structure lurking behind how *nice* the algebra of $\mu$, $\phi$, and the Dirichlet convolution $\star$  operators are.

Is there some place I can find an elementary, but rigorous introduction to these developed entirely algebraically (I feel that the algebraic structure ought to be lattice-y or ring-ey), which is then "instantiated" on number theory? Would I find this developed in, say, an algebraic number theory text?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) states: "In mathematics, a unique factorization domain (UFD) (also sometimes called a factorial ring following the terminology of Bourbaki) is a ring in which a statement analogous to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic holds."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apostol presents the result that the arithmetic functions with respect to addition and Dirichlet product form a *factorial ring*. This is shown in many texts of number theory, but it does not use particular methods from algebraic number theory.